# array as input for function

Tags: function, numpy

i defined a formula and i want to have existing array data as input for this function and return results in an array .

the code

```
x1=np.array(x1)#     <---- existing input data

x_test=[0,5,10,15]    <---- just some test data
x_test=np.array(x_test)

def P_0(x):    
    return 295*(math.cos((0.9952*x+2.25952)*math.pi/180))**2-(295*(math.cos((0.9952*x+1.74)*math.pi/180))**2) 
results=P_0(x_test)
```

i get error:

```
TypeError: Required argument 'shape' (pos 1) not found
```

Comment: `math.` functions are for scalars, though they might work with a single element array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
def P_0(x):    
    return 295*(np.cos((0.9952*x+2.25952)*np.pi/180))**2-(295*(np.cos((0.9952*x+1.74)*np.pi/180))**2)
```

I have just replaced `math.pi` to `np.pi` , `math.sin` to `np.sin` and `math.cos` to `np.cos`

It's always better if you use functions from numpy while doing operations of numpy arrays

Comment: @kevin yes mostly.